# Dynamics NAV service Tier - login failed for ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am setting up a service tier for MS Dynamics NAV 2009, but am unable to connect due to a login failure.

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors.
>
> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11.

I have the following servers:

> SQL Server: sql-dev
>
> Dynamics service tier: dynamicsService

The SQL and Dynamics services are both running under the same domain account.

I have four spns setup:

> MSSQLSvc/sql-dev.mycompany.com:1433
>
> MSSQLSvc/sql-dev:1433
>
> MicrosoftDynamicsNAVServer$Dev/dynamicsService.mycompany.com:7046
>
> MicrosoftDynamicsNAVServer$Dev/dynamicsService:7046

Finally, I have Delegation setup for the domain account for both the Dynamics and SQL service. This looks to be the correct setup according to the MS documentation, but it is not working. Any thoughts to where I have gone wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting SPNs is not enough. Service Account of SQL Server and Dynamics NAV Service Tier are important. Also their permissions, enabling the Object Change Listener and delegating Access to the SQL Server Service.

If you did all the setup described in this MSDN Article [Walkthrough: Installing the Three Tiers on Three Computers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301254.aspx), it should work. I did 60+ Setups of NAV 2009 Service Tier that way in the past.

Unfortunately, Delegation Setup in Dynamics NAV 2009 is complex. I suggest get help from Microsoft Support if you are Microsoft Partner or get help from your Dynamics NAV Partner if you are a customer.